# How do we obtain the Google App Engine safe-URL key in Java for a different appId and namespace?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When I just need to do it for my application without namespace I can use the following code:

```
final Key myKey = KeyFactory.createKey(kind, id);
final String safeUrlKey = KeyFactory.keyToString(myKey);
```

Unfortunately when I need to do it for a different appId or namespace I don't find any way to do it in Java.

In python for example I can use the following code:

```
new_key = db.Key.from_path(entity, id, _app=application_id, namespace=namespace)
return str(new_key)
```

But in Java this doesn't seem to be available.

Any idea on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The App Engine SDK does indeed try to prohibit this, as evidenced by the lack of public classes/methods that can handle app IDs and namespaces. Even in python this is discouraged by the underscore prefix on the `_app` keyword argument. This is probably because App Engine apps are meant to be well-contained within their project.

It is possible to use reflection to workaround these barriers, but *only on the Standard Java 8 runtime* (which is currently in beta). The Standard Java 7 runtime prohibits [reflecting non-accessible methods](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime#reflection). (If you're using App Engine Flex I suspect you'll be ok too, although I haven't tested that.)

If you are already using Java 8 or willing to switch, I was able to create keys for arbitrary app IDs/namespaces with the following:

```
Key createKey(String appId, String namespace, String kind, long id) {
  try {
    Class<?> appNsClazz = Class.forName("com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AppIdNamespace");
    Constructor<?> constructor = appNsClazz.getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
    constructor.setAccessible(true);

    Constructor<Key> keyFactory = Key.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, 
      Key.class, long.class, String.class, appNsClazz);
    keyFactory.setAccessible(true);

    Object appNs = constructor.newInstance(appId, namespace);
    return keyFactory.newInstance(kind, /* parent key */ null, id, /* name */ null, appNs);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | 
           InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException | 
           IllegalAccessException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

If you will be running this code often it would be good to cache the Constructor instances, and the `appNs` instance if possible to avoid the performance overhead of reflection.

Please do note that this code will **not work on the Standard Java 7 runtime**.

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately I am using standard Java 7 runtime, so reflection is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to make it work with the following code (looking at how KeyFactory was doing it internally):

```
public static String getSafeUrlFromId(final String kind, final Long id, final String applicationId, final String namespace) {

    final com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity.Reference myMessage = new com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity.Reference();

    final Element pathElement = new Element().setType(kind).setId(id);
    final Path path = myMessage.getMutablePath();
    path.addElement(pathElement);

    myMessage.setPath(path);

    if (namespace != null){
        myMessage.setNameSpace(namespace);
    }
    myMessage.setApp(applicationId);

    final BaseEncoding encoder = BaseEncoding.base64Url();
    final String alphanumericKey = encoder.omitPadding().encode(myMessage.toByteArray());
    return alphanumericKey;
}
```